# GroovyCastException when calling super constructor

Tags: class, inheritance, groovy

I have an abstract Groovy class `GameScreen` which receives a few arguments in the constructor:

```
GameScreen(game, background, screenSize)
{ ... }
```

Then I derive a child class `LoadingScreen` from the base class. In the constructor of the child class I call the super constructor like this:

```
LoadingScreen(game)
{
    super(game, new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f), Constants.SCREEN_SIZE)
}
```

Where `game` is a non-null object, `new Color()` is clear I guess, and `Constants.SCREEN_SIZE` is another non-null object.

However, when I now run the Groovy application I get the following error on the line at the super constructor call in `LoadingScreen`:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
```

The thing is: I have no idea what this error means. What `int` is this error message referring to? And which object is null? I checked in the debugger and `game` is not null for sure.

Since I had no more ideas I removed all the arguments from the constructor in the base class `GameScreen` and call its constructor from the child constructor then simply as `super()`. However, I still get exactly the same error, so I suspect something else then these arguments are triggering it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post enough code to reproduce the problem? I tried with some assumptions about your code and could instantiate the super class with no problem

Comment: Ok, thanks for asking me for more code -- I was preparing a minimal example and found the problem. I have updated my original posting...

Comment: You can post your update as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refactoring my code a bit I found that in my base class `GameScreen`there is a class variable instantiated like this:

```
int counter = null
```

After changing `null` to `-1` it works now. And of course it makes sense. However, this error message is really misleading, because it was not referring to that line, but to the constructor itself :(